# Update timestamp in jsonb postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

How can I update timestamp in jsonb to value of function now()?

I tried to do smt like this

```
    UPDATE test
    SET column = jsonb_set(column,'{time}',to_char(now(),'some date format'),true)
```

I got error like

```
    'jsonb_set(json,unknown,text,bool) is not available'
```

I think the reason of error  is that value of now() isn't is single quotation marks,because this query is working

```
    UPDATE test
    SET column = jsonb_set(column,'{time}','date with the same date format ',true)
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3):

> `jsonb_set(json,unknown,text,bool) is not available`

PostgreSQL can't find a function with this signature. According to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), the signature is `jsonb_set(jsonb, text[], jsonb, boolean)`.

`to_char()` is returning `text` where you need to have `jsonb`, and a cast should do the trick:

```
jsonb_set(column, '{time}', to_char(now(),'\"some date format\"')::jsonb, true)
```

(Keep in mind that `::jsonb` expects valid JSON as input, e.g. `"` around strings.)

Comment: `UPDATE test.new_orders
     SET properties = jsonb_set(properties,'{at}',to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US')::jsonb,'1',true)`;

[42883] ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, jsonb, unknown, boolean) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: now this `UPDATE test.new_orders
     SET properties = jsonb_set(properties,'{at}',to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US')::jsonb,'1',true)`

Comment: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json Detail: Token "-05" is invalid. Where: JSON data, line 1: 2018-05...

Comment: I alluded to this in my answer. `2018-05` is not valid JSON. `"2018-05"` is a JSON string. Try adding some quotes: `concat('"', to_char(...), '"')::jsonb`.